# Laravel 5 authentication without remember_token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using an existing database, and I'm not allowed to modify the tables, so adding a remember_token is not an option, but without it I'm unable to login. When I try to login Laravel does check the credentials and returns whether they match the records, but it only refreshes the page. I am pretty sure the remember_token is the cause since I've encountered this problem before, but this time I can't add a column to my users table.

Is there a way to use the out-of-the-box authentication without the remember_token?

Comment: you can authenticate the user every time you refresh the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your User model add:

```
  /**
   * Overrides the method to ignore the remember token.
   */
  public function setAttribute($key, $value)
  {
    $isRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();
    if (!$isRememberTokenAttribute)
    {
      parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
  }
```

Credits: https://laravel.io/forum/05-21-2014-how-to-disable-remember-token

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this appears to fix the remember token issue, but the page is still refreshing, but that's a different issue. Thanks again

Answer (score 15):

Since Laravel v5.3.27 you can also disable the remember me functionality by setting the `$rememberTokenName` to `false` in your User model.

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    protected $rememberTokenName = false;

    // ...
}
```

source: [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/e79817724a206bc16824356619d4a9655118c5b8)

Comment: Thank you!
I also removed that column. And then reset password functionality broke
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' error occured when user tried to submit new password. (Hopefully my comment will help in SEO)

Answer (score 1):

In order to really disable the "remember me" functionality and to be sure the remember_token field is not used, add the following code to the boot method of App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.

```
Auth::provider('eloquent', function($app, array $config)
{
  return new class($app['hash'], $config['model']) extends \Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider
  {
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
      return null;
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
      //Do nothing
    }
  };
});
```

assuming a default Laravel setup, the code above will work instantly.

Off course, it can be improved by defining the custom user provider in a seperate file instead of using a anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 9 you could set remember token to empty string, for example:

```
    public function logout()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->setRememberToken('');
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        
        return redirect('login');
    }
```